# Orthornomal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, euclidean-geometry, intuition, orthonormal

Is there a more direct reason for the following:

> If the columns of $n\times n$ square matrix are orthonormal, then its rows are also orthonormal.

The standard proof involves showing that left inverse of a matrix is same as the right inverse and thereby concluding that if $Q^TQ = I$, then $QQ^T = I$. This seems to be more of an algebraic manipulation. Can someone offer me a geometric insight?

---

Thanks

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550967/orthonormal-matrices-intuition  It may give some insight into your problem.

Comment: @amWhy No, I am not.

Comment: @amWhy Ok. So I should accept answers or upvote them or both? Also, what can I do with the $2$ points I get? Can I trade them for something? Also, can you help me with some algebra questions? If so, can you come on chat? Thanks.

Comment: @amWhy Or I can ask you here itself. I have a question in group theory, rather a clarification. I realized somethings yesterday night and want to check if my understanding right? 1) Automorphism group is a sub-group of the permutation group. 2) Any group can be viewed as a subgroup of $S_n$. 3) The anti-automorphism i.e., the element $\sigma^2(g)=g$ is similar to the reflection element in $D_{2n}$.

Comment: Very good. Yes, you're understanding is correct. Are you familiar with Cayley's Theorem? Any finite group of order $n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$, and the same applies to infinite groups, which are isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_\infty$.

Comment: @amWhy No, I am not familiar with Cayley theorem. What about my understanding of the other two questions?

Comment: @amWhy Why should I accept answers? I want many answers and if I accept, it will mean that I am contended with it.

Comment: Only countable infinite groups are isomorphic to $S_\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a geometric insight, but at least it is a proof at the vector level.

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be the columns of $Q$, and $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ its rows. Let also $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be the canonical basis. Then we have
$$
v_j=Qe_j,\ \ w_j=Q^Te_j,\ \ \ j=1,\ldots,n.
$$
And, for all $j,k$,
$$
\langle v_j,e_k\rangle = \langle Qe_j,e_k\rangle=\langle e_j,Q^Te_k\rangle=\langle e_j,w_k\rangle.
$$
Note that for any $x,y$ we have, using that $(e_j)$ is an orthonormal basis, 
$$
\langle x,y\rangle = \sum_{s,t}\langle x,e_s\rangle\langle y,e_t\rangle\langle e_s,e_t\rangle = \sum_t\langle x,e_t\rangle\langle y,e_t\rangle.
$$
Below we will use this equality first for the basis $(e_j)$ and then for the basis $(v_j)$. 
Then
$$
\langle w_j,w_k\rangle=\sum_t\langle w_j,e_t\rangle \langle w_k,e_t\rangle
=\sum_t\langle e_j,v_t\rangle\langle e_k,v_t\rangle=\langle e_j,e_k\rangle,
$$
showing that $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ is orthonormal.

Answer (score 0):

If $Q$ is orthonormal, its transpose is its inverse, and vice versa. Understanding this is key to your question. You are asking for a geometric understanding of this, rather than a symbolic algebra understanding. So let's give that a try.

Because columns are orthonormal, then what does $Q^T$ do to the $i$th column of $Q$? If you are in the habit of seeing matrix multiplication with a vector as a sequence of dot products of rows with that vector (which captures the degree to which the vector is parallel to each of the rows), then you see that $Q^T$ takes the $i$th column to the $i$th standard basis vector.

But then what does $Q$ do to the $i$th standard basis vector? Again if you see matrix multiplication with a vector as a sequence of dot products, then you see that $Q$ applied to the $i$th standard basis vector captures the projection of each of $Q$'s rows onto the $i$th standard basis vector, yielding $Q$'s $i$th column.

We've just established that $Q$ and $Q^T$, as actions on vectors, exchange the set of columns of $Q$ with the set of standard basis vectors. So they are inverse actions.